# How can you determine if a root of a polynomial is a repeated one?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let's say we have the polynomial $x^3 − 12x − 16$, and we know there are 2 roots, $x = -2$, and $x = 4$, and one of those roots appears twice.

How can we determine which of those two roots is the repeated one?

Comment: is $f(x)=(x+2)^2(x-4)$ or $(x-4)^2(x+2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With algebra, you can factor (or do something equivalent, like synthetic division or polynomial long division). Like here you can compute that $\frac{x^3-12x-16}{(x+2)(x-4)}=x+2$ for $x \neq -2,4$.

Another option with algebra is guess-and-check: you can multiply out $(x+2)^2(x-4)$ and $(x-4)^2(x+2)$ and see which one matches.

With calculus, you can take the derivative and plug in the roots; if you get zero at a root, then the point is at least a double root. Higher roots can be checked by taking more derivatives (e.g. $p(0)=p'(0)=p''(0)=0$ with $p'''(0) \neq 0$ means a triple root).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

For this polynomial, the sum of the roots must be $0,$ since that is the coefficient of $x^2$;

$-2+-2+4=0$ and $4+-2+4\ne0,$ so the answer is that $-2$ is repeated.

Comment: I accepted this solution as it is the quickest and easiest method for the example in my question. For more complex problems, the other users' methods (involving differentiation) could be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

You differentiate your polynomial, which will give you $3x^2-12$. Since $-2$ is a root of it, it's $-2$ which is the double root.